# Python Args not working correctly

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have this program that is supposed to allow the user to input a start/end arg as well as a file arg and then the program will open a txt file and read line line    s starting and ending at the args. but if i type in 2 as the start and 10 as the end it gives me the end must be greater than start error. how can i fix this?

```
#/usr/bin/python

# File name: print_lines.py

import sys
print sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[2]
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print "Input: print.py starting ending\n"
    exit ()
if sys.argv[1] >= sys.argv[2]:
    print "Ending line must be larger than the starting line.\n"
    sys.exit()

start = int(sys.argv[1])
end = int(sys.argv[2])
textinput = str(sys.argv[3])
current = 1
try:
    with open(textinput, 'r') as text:
        for line in text:
            if current >= start and current <=end:
                print line
            current += 1
            if current > end:
                break
        else:
            print "End reached, line finishes at", current-1
except IOError:
    print "File not found. \n"
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` entries are always strings. If you want to treat some of the values numerically, you'll need to convert them to `int` **before** comparing them:

```
start = int(sys.argv[1])
end = int(sys.argv[2])
if start >= end:
    print "Ending line must be larger than the starting line.\n"
    sys.exit()
```

Comparing strings is done *lexicographically*; because the character `'1'` comes before the charater `'9'`, `'10'` is smaller than `'9'`; the second character plays no role in that comparison.